# File script searching for versioning

Tags: string, search, cmd

I need to search through all sub directories of a directory and find all files containing a "VERSION" string including a number.
I need to increment this number, so 1.1.2 will be incremented to 1.1.3 etc. and save it in the file again.
I need to run this on Windows machines only, if it makes any difference.

Can I do this with cmd commands or do I need to use a program for this ?

I would like to run this without installing anything if possible.

Comment: `findstr /?` is a good start for that.

Comment: The problem with findstr is that I need to be able to extract a substring of the found string, manipulate it and replace the old string.
I just can not seem to combine the right methods for this.

Comment: you can build a list of all needed files with `findstr /s /m /b "Version" *.*` you should narrow your search for example *.log - or have a lot of time. There are some trheads here, how to change one line in a file. You can do the incremental with `set /a` after disassembling the string with a `for`loop (`delims=.`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a Java program to go through the entire structure.

I found that using CMD commands was too complicated for me to structure, and using a Java program I could also easily reuse parts of the program in different but similar structures elsewhere in my file system.

The CMD usage could my the files for me, but extract a single line, manipulating it and putting it back inside the file was not easy using CMD commands, where as using Java was much easier.